# Reading the object from the file in java

Tags: java

After Executing the below code, the values that are printed are null for the strings. Why? (Ofcourse I have written the object to the file). Can any one help me in this regard?

```
class Demo {
    protected String name;
    protected String address;
}

class Demo1 extends Demo implements Serializable 
{
    transient int age;
    Demo1(String name,String address,int age)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.address=address;
        this.age=age;
    }
}
public class FileRead
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Demo1 ob=new Demo1("Rose","Rohini",23);
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Demo.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            ob = (Demo1) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Demo class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Deserialized Details...");
        System.out.println("Name: " + ob.name);
        System.out.println("Address: " + ob.address);
        System.out.println("age " + ob.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have problem in reading the object`  Exception ? Error ?

Comment: Do you have any kind of questions?

Comment: What is `"Demo.ser"` ??Is it your filename ??

Comment: No Error and No Exception, but the values that are printing is null. why>

Comment: Yes, My filename is "Demo.ser"

Comment: Pleas add the source for Demo that you extend

Comment: Can you paste code of Demo class too

Comment: yes, now you can the program

Comment: The Demo class doesn't implement Serializable, therefore the properties that are declared in that class are not being serialized. To fix this just make `class Demo implements Serializable`, and rewrite the object to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Super class `Demo` is not `Serializable`. So it is not possible to persist the  supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields while persisting `Demo1` object.

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
>   subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
>   of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
>   fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
>   it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
>   class's state.

*Code updated* -

```
class Demo implements Serializable  {
    protected String name;
    protected String address;
}
```

In this case you get out put -

```
Rose - Rohini - 0
```

As age is `transient` so it will not be stored.

Answer (score 1):

you have declared field as "TRANSIENT". Transient field will not be serialized., While reconstructing the object they will have default value. For sting it is null

Update done after pasting demo class code

Fix: your demo class should be

```
class Demo implements Serializable  {
    protected String name;
    protected String address;
}
```

If you want age also to be serialized then change
transient int age; -- > int age ;

Comment: its only the age thats transient? Should not give null for the others unless the demo class holds transisents

Comment: Since the code of demo is not pasted, I assume even in Demo the fields would declared as transient.  It is one of the reason for fields to have default values on reconstruction

Comment: Why can't you assume that the file OP is de-serializing is the problem? Assumptions are not good enough to post answers!

Comment: I would rather assume that since the Demo1 class is implementing Serializable that Demo class would not implement Serializable and hence probably not hold transient parameters

Answer (score 1):

After doing the following 3 changes in your code, it worked.

First

```
class Demo {
```

is changed to

```
class Demo  implements Serializable {
```

Make your class `Demo` serializable, since you need to serialize it.

Next

```
class Demo1 extends Demo implements Serializable {
```

is changed to

```
class Demo1 extends Demo {
```

No need to implement Serializable for `Demo1` as it extends `Demo` which is Serializable.

And finally,

```
transient int age;
```

is changed to

```
int age;
```

Remove the `transient` from age, as `transient` fields won't be serialized.

**P.S:** If not don't intend to serialize `age`, let it be `transient`. I gave that change, because you had that in your sysout.

Answer (score 0):

Make the super class "Demo" in this case implements Serializable. So, that your code works fine.